# WCF Authentication doesn't work

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have created a Service with below Service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
     [OperationContract]
     string GetData(int value);
}
```

With below Custom Authentication (not in App_Code)

```
public class CustomAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userName.Equals("user") && password.Equals("pass"))
            {
                //Good to go
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException("Authentication failed");
        }
    } 
}
```

My Config on Service.  I used basicHttpBinding with Custom User Authentication (I don't want to use wsHttpBinding which  makes it mandatory to have certificate)

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBasicBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding" contract="TestService.IService1" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="TestService.CustomAuthenticator,TestService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
```

Service is hosted on IIS 8.5 with Anonymous and Forms Authentications enabled.  I took a Console application client, added service reference and below config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://techspider/Service/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But, when I call a method on the service, it seems to be accepting any user name / password, which makes me think that it is not going to the custom authentication class I implemented.

If I don't supply any `UserName`, it is throwing me an error which indicates my setup is correct.

```
   Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
    client.GetData(1);
```

> The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

The below code even after supplying wrong credentials, was able to fetch me the output.

```
Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "aaaa";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "dddd";
client.GetData(1);
```

Can anyone suggest if I'm missing any Config on Server?  How do I ensure my `CustomAuthenticator` gets executed with every method call.  I searched a number of questions online but none of them resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feeling that each and every username password combination will be accepted is right. That's the case because you're not really validating the credentials.

```
if (userName.Equals("user") && password.Equals("pass"))
{
    //Good to go
}
```

If these demo-credentials are submitted, you're *good to go* ;-) But what if this doesn't apply? If any other username password combination is submitted, then *nothing* happens! And that's exactly the reason why your service is accepting arbitrary credentials. In the `catch`-block you're throwing an informative `FaultException`, but it won't be triggered as long as there doesn't occur an exception (which isn't the case in this simple example).

If you take a look at the docs, there's a [very important remark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.validate(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) and a corresponding code sample:

> Override the Validate method to specify how the username and password is validated. If the username and password do not pass validation, then throw a SecurityTokenValidationException.

So instead of doing nothing if the submitted credentials don't match you should throw a `SecurityTokenValidationException` to reject the login-attempt.

```
public class CustomAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (userName.Equals("user") && password.Equals("pass"))
            {
                //Good to go
            }
            else
            {
                // add this line
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException("Authentication failed");
        }
    } 
}
```